# python changing string quotes

Tags: python, pandas

I'm iterating through a pandas dataframe and fetch values:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    st= row.values
```

I have a column called text where the value is

```
"current user's role"
```

I would like to convert that to (single quotes and a backslash in front the apostrophe in user's

```
'current user\'s role'
```

I would like to get the backslash also inserted to the string. I'm tryning to make a DML (insert) statement here

Comment: String delimiters are not part of the string's content. The string's content is just `current user's role`.

Comment: How will that help you to get what you want?

Comment: its not the same thing.. I'm trying to make a DML statement (insert into table values ().. I would like to get the text in single quotes with a backslash infront of the apostraphe character which would make it work.